# Deploy a angular 6 project without angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular6

I am looking to deploy a project angular (angular 6) to a host (OVH). I did not create my application with Angular CLI so I can't use *"ng build "*

I've been looking for several weeks 
What should I do ?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: how are you building and testing your app so far??

Comment: with node (npm start)

Comment: well I mean which tools are you using ? webpack, gulp, grunt, /// ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty solution:

- create a new empty project with `ng new`
- delete all source files
- copy your source files in the `src/app/` folder

Comment: Your solution works well for me but I have a error with RXJS. When I do  "import {Observable} from ' rxjs/Observable '; "
Angular doesn't seem to find an exported member: ' Observable ' yet the rxjs folder is present in the node-module folder

Comment: have you followed https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md ?
Now you have to do
```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a build tool like webpack/gulp/grunt/etc you can write a script to transpile all the `.ts` files down to js and html/scss as well. Then you just serve your dist.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to read this, and than come up with a solution.

https://blog.angularindepth.com/setting-up-angular-from-scratch-1f518c65d8ab

Answer (score -1):

You can add angular cli to your npm, it is global not project specific

```
npm install -g @angular/cli

than simply write:

ng build —prod

Take the files inside /dist dir and simply put  them on a web server

Good luck
```

Comment: He said he cannot use `ng build` because his project is not managed with @angular/cli